# C# Edit some parameters in json but save untouched parameters

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON string like this:

```
{
    "param1": "value1",
    "param2": "value2",
    "param3": "value3",
    "somearray1": {
        "inarrparam1": "inarrvalue1",
        "inarrparam2": "inarrvalue2"
    },
    "param4": "value4",
    "somearray2": {
        "inarrparam3": "inarrvalue3",
        "inarrparam4": "inarrvalue4"
    }
}
```

In my JSON string there are more parameters and arrays.
I want to edit JSON string value, e.g `value1`, `value3` and `inarrvalue1`.
Then, I need to save edited string with all parameters and values with or without the same order as the string was. How can I do this?

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me that preservation of field order is a feature that a JSON reader/writer would be concerned with. If ordering is important, then you need to encode this in the data, not rely on the transit format to do it for you.

Comment: According to the JSON specification "An object is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs". It looks to me like almost everything in your JSON there should be an array

Comment: You are not telling us what are you updating wether it is entity model or something else? For instance entity model has method Patch, in other cases taking the origincal and trying to map to it using automapper can of help.

Answer (score 0):

one way of achieving it is to deserialize the json to typed C# object,edit the properties and serialize it back to json-

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("json String");
obj.param1 = "new Value1";
obj.param3 = "new Value3";
obj.somearray1.inarrparam1 = "new inarrvalue1";

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

where `RootObject` is the top most parent type.

**OUTPUT**

```
{
  "param1": "new Value1",
  "param2": "value2",
  "param3": "new Value3",
  "somearray1": {
    "inarrparam1": "new inarrvalue1",
    "inarrparam2": "inarrvalue2"
  },
  "param4": "value4",
  "somearray2": {
    "inarrparam3": "inarrvalue3",
    "inarrparam4": "inarrvalue4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to write all the parameters in those classes?

Comment: I'm afraid yes. You'll need to construct a strongly typed c# object. Try http://www.json2csharp.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that

```js
var data = {
  "param1": "value1",
  "param2": "value2",
  "param3": "value3",
  "somearray1": {
    "inarrparam1": "inarrvalue1",
    "inarrparam2": "inarrvalue2"
  },
  "param4": "value4",
  "somearray2": {
    "inarrparam3": "inarrvalue3",
    "inarrparam4": "inarrvalue4"
  }
};

data.param1 = 'newValue1';
data.somearray1.inarrparam1 = 'newInarrvalue1';
console.log(data);
```

**Edit**

If you want to update this `json string` using `C#`, you can simply use `string.replace()` function to update.

Comment: Isn't that javascript?

Comment: `string.Replace()` will replace all `value1`, which isn't desireable. For example `inarrvalue1` with `inarrnewvalue1`.